# Не могу передать переменную внутрь метода

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, bs4

Этот вопрос звучит как нубский, но меня эта ситуация завела в тупик.
Как передать значение внутрь метода findAll?

Пытался и так и эдак:

```
nrk_all = ["'article', class_='article'"]
nrk_all = "'article', class_='article'"
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, 'html.parser')
```

Не работает:

```
list_news = soup.findAll(nrk_all[0])
list_news = soup.findAll(nrk_all)
```

Работает:

```
list_news = soup.findAll('article', class_='article')
```

Comment: Чем не устраивает тот вариант, что работает?

Comment: Так надо, чтобы сделать одну функцию, а не 50.
В дальнейшем переменная будет состоять из массива, а далее будут перебираться значения...ну и т.д.

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Покажите, пример, как "переменная будет состоять из массива ну и т.д."

Comment: list = ["table, class='table'", "id, class='someclass'"]
for i in list:
    list_news = soup.findAll(list[i])

Comment: Это должно быть в вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

Вот рабочий пример:

```
def f(id, class_):
    print(f'id={id} kwargs={class_}')

list = [
 (('table',), {'class_': 'table'}),
 (('id',), {'class_': 'someclass'}),
]
for args, kwargs in list:
   list_news = f(*args, **kwargs)
```

В вашем коде замените вызов `f` на `soup.findAll`.

Выше в примере общий случай, для произвольных параметров. Если нужно передавать только одно значение в позиционных параметрах, то можно упростить:

```
list = [
 ('table', {'class_': 'table'}),
 ('id', {'class_': 'someclass'}),
]
for arg, kwargs in list:
   list_news = f(arg, **kwargs)
```

Comment: К сожалению, не работает. Он как будто обрезает кавычки....

Comment: Лан, просто пересмотрю готовые парсеры на супе, наверняка кто-то делал подобное.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, оно при передаче почему-то удаляло нижнее подчеркивание у class_

Поэтому список такой:

```
ski_nordi = [['a' ,'headlinelink'], ['div', 'nameofclass']]
```

А запрос такой:

```
for i in ski_nordi:
    list_news = soup.findAll(ski_nordi[i][0], class_=ski_nordi[i][1], limit=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Метод [find_all](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) первым параметром принимает `name`:

> Method signature: find_all(name, attrs, recursive, string, limit,
> **kwargs)

Значит, если вы хотите передавать через объекты в аргументы метода, то нужна распаковка:

```
nrk_all = {
    'name': 'article', 
    'class_': 'article',
}
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, 'html.parser')
list_news = soup.findAll(**nrk_all)
```

Для списка это выглядело бы так:

```
nrk_all_items = [
    {
        'name': 'article', 
        'class_': 'article',
    },
    {
        'name': 'article', 
        'class_': 'article',
    },
]
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, 'html.parser')
for nrk_all in nrk_all_items:
    list_news = soup.findAll(**nrk_all)
```